# Draw a rounded rectangle border with cutout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, android-drawable

I need to a rounded border in Xamarin.Forms, as i need to customize the thickness i can't go with existing `Frame` class.

[image: Expected output for border]

**Constraints**

- Green background is not permanent value, it can be changed dynamically.
- Gap width is also dynamic one.
- Able to change corner radius, thickness and color of the border.

I came across some class in Java for similar implementation  [CutoutDrawable](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/9ca33544acd643eea74a72e5200f26ee4ad1efcd/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/CutoutDrawable.java)

Without using SkiaSharp in Xamarin.Forms, kindly do share your suggestion to achieve this in custom renderers.

Comment: hey, why aren't you considering Skia?

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk, Is there a way in Skia for it?

Comment: @JoyRex You can use NGraphics/NControl to draw that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Porter-Duff` mode is option available to achieve my requirement. Each platforms contains its own API for this approach.